# Как оптимизировать картинки svg для seo

Tags: svg, seo, svg-спрайт

Имеется один спрайт svg из нескольких десятков картинок. Все картинки на сайте подключаются через use. Как можно оптимизировать такие картинки для seo. Прописать текст и тайтлы. Вообще как впринципе поисковики относятся к таким картинками и спрайтам. Умееют ли они читать такие файлы с использованием use и спрайтов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поисковики читают и запоминают содержание SVG файлов, как обыкновенный текст HTML страничек. 
Кроме того в svg файле можно неограниченное число раз применять теги - 
`<title>.... </title>` - заголовок фрагмента кода
`<desc>.... </desc>` - любой текст, описывающий содержание фрагмента кода
Место расположения этих тегов никак не регламентировано, поэтому всё равно, где вы их разместили, хоть в файле спрайта, хоть в самой иконке спрайта.

**Пример включения тегов в файл спрайта**

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <title> Спрайт социальных иконок </title> 
    <desc> Спрайт содержит коллекцию оригинальных цветных иконок социальных 
    сетей</desc> 
  <symbol id="twitter"> 
     <title>социальная иконка твиттера </title> 
      <desс> иконка выполнена в стиле ретро </desc> 
      <path> .. ваш код иконки .. </path> 
   </symbol> 
     <symbol id="facebook">  
         <title>социальная иконка фэйсбук </title> 
      <desс> иконка выполнена в стиле ретро </desc> 
      <path> .. ваш код иконки .. </path> 
    </symbol>  
 </svg>
```

Всё, что находится в тегах `<title>`и `<desc>`  будет проиндексировано поисковиками.

**Пример включения описательных тегов  к вызовам иконок командой `use`**

```
<svg> 
 <g> 
 <title>социальная иконка твиттера </title> 
          <desс> иконка выполнена в стиле ретро /desc> 

  <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: только не понятен один момент как в результатах выдачи будут отображаться эти картинки, я увижу саму картинку или какую текстовую информация из title и desc

Comment: @ruslik посетители сайта будут видеть только картинку SVG без текстовой инфы, которая  размещена в title и desc, так что пишите там, что угодно,- никто не увидит, кроме вас и поисковика.